# How do I add CSS files to HTML in Intellij?

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

I'm building a web application in Intellij, and have my HTMl written as a String in Intellij. In the header, I included the line:

```
"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\" />\n" +
```

which should use the included stylesheet in my project's base directory, but it's not doing anything.

The CSS file works when I run the HTMl as a normal HTMl file outside of Intellij. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Do you have the "CSS" plugin enabled? What do you see on completion in href? May you share a screenshot like that: https://i.imgur.com/3jM9NQf.png

Answer (score 0):

Just create your css file in webapp folder, and link it in head of your html file.

link rel="stylesheet" href="your css file"